# Selenium Python execute script in the Firefox console

Tags: python, selenium

I am able to run the following script in Google Chrome console. How can I do this using Selenium Python in Firefox?

```
date1 = "13-11-2015T17:25"
date2 = "25-11-2015T11:01"
window.PF.start_diff(date1, date2)
```

I tried with `driver.executeScript()`, but I do not think I can achieve with this.
This is what I am trying when I am in the Firefox and Google Chrome console. First I log in to the app and execute the script and this is what I get:

[image]

So it seems like it is working. Note that the pop up appears after executing the command.

I have tried using both of the following:

```
driver.execute_script("window.PF.start_diff(date1, date2)")
driver.execute_script(window.PF.start_diff(date1, date2))
```

Also tried this: `driver.execute_async_script`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are not defining date1 and date2, try the following:

```
driver.execute_script("date1 = '13-11-2015T17:25'; date2 = '25-11-2015T11:01'; return window.PF.start_diff(date1, date2);")
```

Comment: thank you so much. I was defining it outside the script. It works now